# Get comma delimited distinct rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table similar to below. What I am trying to build is a query that returns distinct vendor concatenated string in order of `EID desc`. In below example it should return

```
045-FH;799-HD;67-3M

Eid   Vendor
1      67-3M
2      67-3M
3      67-3M
4      799-HD
5      799-HD
6      045-FH
7      045-FH
```

This is what SQL query I have but unable to use order by and distinct at same time. Any help is appreciated.

```
select distinct vendor
from tblVendor
order by Eid
```

Comment: @SalmanA I don't think that the concatenation was the only goal for the question here, rather the grouping and the ordering as well.  Should be reopened with maybe just a reference to the "duplicate" question I think?

Comment: @squillman reopened

Comment: @user3038399 ignoring the duplicates issue for now, how were you converting the results of this query to a comma separated string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this.  The `CTE` ensures the list is unique.  The ordering of the string aggregation is handled by `WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Eid DESC)`.

```
with unq_cte as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by Vendor order by Eid desc) rn
    from (values (1, '67-3M'),
                 (2, '67-3M'),
                 (3, '67-3M'),
                 (4, '799-HD'),
                 (5, '799-HD'),
                 (6, '045-FH'),
                 (7, '045-FH')) tblVendor(Eid, Vendor))
select string_agg(Vendor, ',') within group (order by Eid desc)
from unq_cte
where rn=1;
```

```
(No column name)
045-FH,799-HD,67-3M
```

[Edit] Alternately, you could use SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES to ensure the vendor list is unique

```
with unq_cte as (
    select top 1 with ties *
    from (values (1, '67-3M'),
                 (2, '67-3M'),
                 (3, '67-3M'),
                 (4, '799-HD'),
                 (5, '799-HD'),
                 (6, '045-FH'),
                 (7, '045-FH')) tblVendor(Eid, Vendor)
     order by row_number() over (partition by Vendor order by Eid desc))
select string_agg(Vendor, ',') within group (order by Eid desc)
from unq_cte;
```

[Edit 2] Prior to 2017 you could use `STUFF` and `FOR XML` to aggregate the string (instead of `STRING_AGG`)

```
with unq_cte as (
    select top 1 with ties *
    from (values (1, '67-3M'),
                 (2, '67-3M'),
                 (3, '67-3M'),
                 (4, '799-HD'),
                 (5, '799-HD'),
                 (6, '045-FH'),
                 (7, '045-FH')) tblVendor(Eid, Vendor)
     order by row_number() over (partition by Vendor order by Eid desc))
select stuff((select ' ' + vendor
             from unq_cte
             order by Eid desc
             for xml path('')), 1, 1, '');
```

Comment: Certainly the right answer provided 2017+    +1

Comment: I am getting error as string_agg is not a recognized built in function name. My sql server version seems done not support this function.

Comment: @user3038399 you can google "string_agg pre SQL 2017"

Comment: @user3038399 it's been updated.  Please review

Comment: `for xml path(''), type).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)', 1, len(' '), '')` would be the correct way to do it pre 2017